# Encrypt plaintext password in AutoHotkey file

Tags: windows, encryption, autohotkey

I automated my Yahoo! login process with AutoHotkey.

It works fine, but problem is that when running this `.ahk` file, anybody can open the script and see the password.

Is there a way I could encrypt this password?

Comment: If you encrypt the password somehow, AHK will have to decrypt it automatically. Once again, this makes your password available to anyone.

Comment: no on the gui where it pasted it looks **** so that won't be problem.

Comment: 1. Inspecting the AHK source code will tell you the encrypted password and how to decrypt it. 2. In Chrome, e.g., you can right-click the password field, click **Inspect element and change the input's type from *password* to *text*. No more asterisks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) can compile your AHK script to an executable (.exe) with its build-in tool [ahk2exe](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe).
The compiler encrypts your source data and its hard to decompile it. (But its not impossible)

[image]

**Edit:** To my knowledge it is not possible to just encrypt a single string within a script and leave the rest untouched. Encrypting the whole script will be the way to go.

Comment: WARNING: For the current version of AHK, this does NOT appear to encrypt the contents of the script in any way whatsoever.  I just tested this and found that just opening the resulting EXE in Notepad++ allows you to view the full text of the original script in its entirety (search for "<COMPILER:").

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is reading this in 2023+, a more secure approach is to rely on the Windows Credential Manager, per this [forum post](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=112391).

This function by user "geek" can retrieve the credentials:

```
CredRead(name)
{
    DllCall("Advapi32.dll\CredReadW"
    , "Str", name   ; [in]  LPCWSTR      TargetName
    , "UInt", 1     ; [in]  DWORD        Type = CRED_TYPE_GENERIC (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/ns-wincred-credentiala)
    , "UInt", 0     ; [in]  DWORD        Flags
    , "Ptr*", pCred ; [out] PCREDENTIALW *Credential
    , "UInt") ; BOOL
    if !pCred
        return
    name := StrGet(NumGet(pCred + 8 + A_PtrSize * 0, "UPtr"), 256, "UTF-16")
    username := StrGet(NumGet(pCred + 24 + A_PtrSize * 6, "UPtr"), 256, "UTF-16")
    len := NumGet(pCred + 16 + A_PtrSize * 2, "UInt")
    password := StrGet(NumGet(pCred + 16 + A_PtrSize * 3, "UPtr"), len/2, "UTF-16")
    DllCall("Advapi32.dll\CredFree", "Ptr", pCred)
    return {"name": name, "username": username, "password": password}
}
```

Call it with `creds := CredRead("[Credential Name]")`.